# How to "lift" a transitive group action on a manifold?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces, covering

Let $M=G/H$ be a homogeneous manifold, with $G$ connected Lie group. Suppose that  $\widetilde{M}$ is a covering of $M$.

> QUESTION: is there a general prescription to obtain a Lie group  $\widetilde{G}$, starting from $G$, in such a way that $\widetilde{M}=\widetilde{G}/\widetilde{H}$?

Using the case of $M=G=S^1$ and $H=1$ as a toy model (and, for instance, $\widetilde{M}=\widetilde{G}=\mathbb{{R}}$) we see that $\widetilde{G}$ has two remarkable properties:

1) it contains the group $\Gamma=\mathbb{{Z}}$ of "gauge symmetries" of $\widetilde{M}\to M$;

2) its factor by $\Gamma$ returns the original group $G$.

So, I guess that the  two properties above are enough to characterise $\widetilde{G}$ but I'm not able to prove it. I'm sure it's a well-known result, but I can't find any reference (I could not get which book is this "Bredon" mentioned here: [lifting group action](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158341/lifting-group-action)). In the case that my guess is correct, I'd like to understand if there is a constructive way to obtain $\widetilde{G}$, e.g., by realising the Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ as vector fields on $M$, lifting them to $\widetilde{M}$, and then take the group generated by their flows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is connected, take its Lie algebra, acting as vector fields on $M$. Lift the vector fields by the covering map. There is a unique connected Lie group $\tilde{G}$ acting on $\tilde{M}$ whose Lie algebra has this action, by a theorem of Dick Palais: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie%E2%80%93Palais_theorem

Comment: Indeed. This is more or less what I suggested in my last lines. I'm aware of Lie-Palais theorem, though you need to require some extra topological conditions from $\widetilde{M}$. Still, I'd like to see some universal property characterising $\widetilde{G}$, like, e.g., "it is the unique group admitting $G$ as a factor by covering transformations", or something like that, and/or some algebraic way to construct it out of the available data!

Comment: The only extra condition you need on $\tilde{M}$ is that it is connected.

Comment: The fundamental group of $G$ lies inside the universal covering group of $G$. The group $\Gamma$ you want is the subgroup of $\pi_1(G)$ which maps trivially to $\pi_1(M)$ when a loop in $G$ carries a base point of $M$ around.

Comment: Don't you need $\widetilde{M}$ to be compact?

Comment: You only need the Lie algebra action to be complete upstairs, which is automatic because it is complete downstairs and intertwines with the covering map.

Comment: @VítTuček: yes, actually in the cases I'm interested in, $\widetilde{M}$ is compact.

Comment: @BenMcKay: incidentally, can you always realise $\frak{g}$, the Lie algebra of $G$, as an algebra of vector fields on $M$, i.e., can you embed it into the (infinite-dimensional) Lie algebra of vector fields on $M$?

Comment: @G_infinity: you cannot always embed every Lie algebra into the Lie algebra of vector fields on every manifold. For example, you cannot embed the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$ into the vector fields on the circle, or else $SU(2)$ would have a nontrivial action on the circle, and by compactness would have a compact orbit, so the circle itself, with stabilizer of a point a closed subgroup of codimension 1, i.e. dimension 2. But the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$ is cross product, so you can picture the cross product on a plane in 3-dimensions: no invariant plane. So no subgroup of dimension 2.

Answer (score 3):

The Palais theorem  assumes  that  the manifold $\tilde M$ is  compact.
The positive  answer   gives proposition 6   of  the  Onishchik  book "Topology of   transitive transformation  groups".
It  states :
 For  any  action  of  a Lie  group $G$  on a manifold and  any  covering
$\pi : N \to M$  there is  an action  of  the  universal  cover $\tilde{G}$ on
$N$   which  cover  the  action  of $G$ on $M$, i.e.  such  that  the  projection $\pi : N \to M$ is $\tilde{G}$-equivariant.

Comment: Welcome to Math Overflow, @Dmitri Alekseevsky!

Comment: It seems that Palais doesn't assume compactness of any manifold in his book. He assumes completeness of a finite dimensional Lie algebra of vector fields. The wikipedia entry simplifies the presentation of the result, by assuming compactness of the manifold, in order to ensure completeness of the vector fields.